# How to optimize a SQL consult to get a inventary for a specific date?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to create a database. Basically, each record is a person register, with birthdate, death date, and location.

One of purposes is to get the number of alive people for each date in  a period of time.
For example:

```
1MAY95: 1045043 people
2MAY95: 1045163 people
3MAY95: 1045351 people
```

and so on.

What I do now, given a date, I start to scan the records 150 years earlier. I picked 150 years because nobody can live more than this number of years.

It is really slow because the database can have millions of records and most of records are died at the date, but I do not know how can I mix 2 index (birthdate and death date).

What algorithm could I use to optimize the consult?

Comment: Hm, `WHERE birthdate < somedate AND deathdate > somedate` is running to long? Are those columns indexed? What is your current query, and what does an `EXPLAIN` show?

Comment: "WHERE birthdate < somedate AND deathdate > somedate" works fine for one specific date. What I need is to get the inventory day by day between two dates. A common question that I have is something like daily inventory for MAY 1990 and by location.